# How to create a circular spinning navigation bar

Tags: html, css, canvas, svg

I am having problems creating a Navigation bar that can spin in a circle in CSS3 and HTML. How can I do this? Below is a picture of the idea from an old game. I want the same animation type that it uses. When it is on the active circle, the page is shown. As you move left and right, the page will change. Is there a way to accomplish this? How can I create this in CSS3 and HTML5.

I have added a code snippet of what I have done so far as a basic idea. I need two buttons that would allow the animation to move left or right instead of 1,2,3,4.

The idea comes from SliderDock. A dock for Windows and MacOS.
CSS3 should be able to accomplish this task if i'm not mistaken.

http://img05.deviantart.net/d13f/i/2011/139/7/4/altimit_mine_os_by_tenshi_no_chi-d3gowsq.png

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/*HEADER*/

.header {
  height: 25px;
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  font: 10px/25px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.header a {
  color: #999;
}
/*WRAPPER*/

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 370px;
}
.menu a {
  margin-right: -4px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 15px/25px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.menu a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
/*INNER CIRCLE*/

.wrapper:before {
  content: "Menu";
  text-align: center;
  font: 30px/120px Georgia, Times, serif;
  color: #black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 110px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
/*MAIN CIRCLE*/

.circle {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #white;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
/*LITTLE CIRCLES*/

.circle li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  font: 20px/50px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.circle li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 15px;
  left: 125px;
}
.circle li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 125px;
  left: 235px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.circle li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 235px;
  left: 125px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.circle li:nth-child(4) {
  top: 125px;
  left: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
/*HOVER STATES*/

.menu > .one:hover ~ .circle {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.menu > .two:hover ~ .circle {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.menu > .three:hover ~ .circle {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.menu > .four:hover ~ .circle {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="description" content="description">

  <title>Nav Menu</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="header"></div>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#" class="one">1</a>
      <a href="#" class="two">2</a>
      <a href="#" class="three">3</a>
      <a href="#" class="four">4</a>

      <div class="circle">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>World</li>
          <li>Games</li>
          <li>AboutUs</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: You'll need to use javascript to reach this job properly (if i'm understanding well what you're trying to ask), take a look on AjaxShake to see if there's something that can serve you (i remember to see some full page js scripts that i think can accomplish it) http://www.ajaxshake.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. you can do it with CSS3 also. To do this use animation rotate on hover of that numbers and rotate the menu image.
2. you can do it by using javascript with onmousehover and onmouseleave event.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript at all. I am in college right now for HTML5 and CSS/CSS5 and wanted to create my special nav bar for my web page, which i'm going to use for my actual company web page. I just don't know how to make it really work. Any Ideas?     http://www.dothack.org/blogs/entry/1-altimit-mine-os-active/
and
http://orig00.deviantart.net/3584/f/2009/004/3/d/altimit_silver_1280_by_trinityrenee.jpg are both examples of the idea.

Comment: Can you explain briefly what you want because the images can't able to explain much about your thinking.

Comment: Well I want to place multiple cogs on the page in a circular design like in the picture. I want to be able to rotate the cogs left or right to change the active cog which is the current info that is being displayed on the page in a set area. Which you could use the set area to enter another page with a Enter button or Use the cog itself as a link to another page.